# Filtering tuples within a range from a reference list

Tags: python, list, filter, tuples

I have a reference list of tuples containing different range of values.

```
[(1042, 1056), (895, 922), (966, 995), (692, 716), (667, 690), 
 (667, 690), (667, 690), (479, 508), (1112, 1578)]
```

I have the following list of lists containing tuple of values which has to be compared against the reference list.

```
[  [(450,470)],
   [(100, 200), (500, 700)],
   [(0, 29), (3827, 3856)],
   [(820, 835), (1539, 1554)],
   [(622, 635), (1286, 1299), (1585, 1598), (1607, 1620)],
   [(637, 642), (780, 785), (1341, 1346), (1944, 1949), (2044, 2049),
    (2158, 2163), (2594, 2599), (2643, 2648)]  ]
```

I am trying to pick one tuple from each list which is in the range of tuples present in  the reference list.

The conditions I considered are :

1. If the input list contains no tuple which has a value in the range of reference list, then any tuple can be taken. For example `[(0, 29), (3827, 3856)]` is not in the range of  the reference list so, I can take any of the tuple. By default I append the first tuple in the list to the reference list.
2. If a tuple within the range of the reference list is found, then that tuple is appended to the reference list and stops searching in that loop. Example is `[(622, 635), (1286, 1299), (1585, 1598), (1607, 1620)]`
3. If more than one tuple is also present in the range of reference list, then the first found tuple is appended to the reference list. Example is `[(637, 642), (780, 785), (1341, 1346), (1944, 1949), (2044, 2049), (2158, 2163), (2594, 2599), (2643, 2648)]`
4. Values in a tuple will never be same and second value in a tuple will always be larger than the first value.

The logic I used to find the range is I took the minimum value and maximum value in the first position of tuple of the reference list. The I did simple iteration.

Code I used is

```
tag_pos_refin = [(1042, 1056), (895, 922), (966, 995), (692, 716), (667, 690), 
                 (667, 690), (667, 690), (479, 508), (1112, 1578)]

tag_pos_db = [  [(450,470)],
                [(100, 200), (500, 700)],
                [(0, 29), (3827, 3856)],
                [(820, 835), (1539, 1554)],
                [(622, 635), (1286, 1299), (1585, 1598), (1607, 1620)],
                [(637, 642), (780, 785), (1341, 1346), (1944, 1949), (2044, 2049), (2158, 2163), 
                  (2594, 2599), (2643, 2648)]
            ]


min_threshold = min(tag_pos_refin)[0]
max_threshold = max(tag_pos_refin)[0]

for tag_pos in tag_pos_db:
    if len(tag_pos) == 1:
        tag_pos_refin.extend(tag_pos)

for tag_pos in tag_pos_db:
    if len(tag_pos) > 1:
        for j in tag_pos:
            if j[0] in range(min_threshold, max_threshold):
                tag_pos_refin.append(j)
                break
            elif min(tag_pos)[0] not in range(min_threshold, max_threshold):
                tag_pos_refin.append(j)
                break             

print(tag_pos_refin)
```

**Output Obtained**

```
[(1042, 1056), (895, 922), (966, 995), (692, 716), (667, 690), (667, 690), (667, 690), (479, 508), (1112, 1578), (450, 470), (100, 200), (0, 29), (820, 835), (622, 635), (637, 642)]
```

**Desired Output**

```
[(1042, 1056), (895, 922), (966, 995), (692, 716), (667, 690), (667, 690), (667, 690), (479, 508), (1112, 1578), (450, 470), (500, 700), (0, 29), (820, 835), (622, 635), (637, 642)]
```

My doubt is

Is it possible to write the code in a better way or better logic for finding the range so that instead of `(100,200)`, the best tuple is `(500,700)`.

(Use case of this is bit complicated to explain: But the values of a tuple can be considered as index point of words or sentences in a text)

Comment: (1) Why do you skip `tag_pos` with less than two tuples? That criteria isn't included in your list of conditions. (2) The third conditions seems redundant, given that you stop searching when the first item is found. (3) Why do you only check the first element of each tuple? What about overlapping values like `(600, 1200)`, where the first element is in range, but the second isn't? (4) The current logic of your code seems broken, since for a value like `[(0, 0), (500, 700)]`, it will append `(0, 0)`, even though the second element is in range.

Comment: 1. If the list contains only one tuple, no need to check. Just add that tuple to the reference list ( forgot to mention in the code).. 2. Yeah you are right. 3. 600 is still in range. That is fine.. so we can select that. 4. Both values in a tuple will never be same. And second value in a tuple will always be larger than first. (Will include this in question)

Comment: Why is there no need to check (and, in any case, your code *does not* add the tuple to the list, because it never checks it).

Comment: I will add that to the question too.

Comment: (4) You missed the point. What about `[(100, 200), (500, 700)]`? Your code will append `(100, 200)`, rather than `(500, 700)`. Why?

Comment: I added for length less than 2. Yeah I see the point about `[(100, 200), (500, 700)]` . Thats what I need to work on now. Is there a better logic. Or how to include `(500,700)` instead of `(100,200)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code. Firstly, you need to check *both* values of every tuple, since either one could be in range, but not necessarily *both*. Secondly, it's inefficient to constantly re-create a `range` object to make a simple bounds check, and your implementation also has an off-by-one error (assuming you want an *inclusive* range). Thirdly, you don't check all tuples when looking for a match, which means the wrong tuple may be appended.

In the solution below, I have added some extra tests to check boundary cases:

```
tag_pos_refin = [(1042, 1056), (895, 922), (966, 995), (692, 716), (667, 690),
                 (667, 690), (667, 690), (479, 508), (1112, 1578)]

tag_pos_db = [
    [(200, 1500), (1112, 1200)], # test upper bound
    [(100, 1600), (275, 479)], # test lower bound
    [(450, 470)],
    [(100, 200), (500, 700)],
    [(0, 29), (3827, 3856)],
    [(820, 835), (1539, 1554)],
    [(622, 635), (1286, 1299), (1585, 1598), (1607, 1620)],
    [(637, 642), (780, 785), (1341, 1346), (1944, 1949), (2044, 2049), (2158, 2163),
     (2594, 2599), (2643, 2648)],
    ]

min_threshold = min(tag_pos_refin)[0]
max_threshold = max(tag_pos_refin)[0]

print(f'min/max: {min_threshold}-{max_threshold}\n')

for tag_pos in tag_pos_db:
    if tag_pos:
        print(f'checking {tag_pos}', end='')
        for j in tag_pos:
            if (min_threshold <= j[0] <= max_threshold or
                min_threshold <= j[1] <= max_threshold):
                print(' -> found match')
                tag_pos_refin.append(j)
                break
        else:
            print(' -> no matches')
            tag_pos_refin.append(tag_pos[0])
        print(f'APPENDED: {tag_pos_refin[-1]}\n')

print(f'RESULT: {tag_pos_refin}\n')
```

Output:

```
min/max: 479-1112

checking [(200, 1500), (1112, 1200)] -> found match
APPENDED: (1112, 1200)

checking [(100, 1600), (275, 479)] -> found match
APPENDED: (275, 479)

checking [(450, 470)] -> no matches
APPENDED: (450, 470)

checking [(100, 200), (500, 700)] -> found match
APPENDED: (500, 700)

checking [(0, 29), (3827, 3856)] -> no matches
APPENDED: (0, 29)

checking [(820, 835), (1539, 1554)] -> found match
APPENDED: (820, 835)

checking [(622, 635), (1286, 1299), (1585, 1598), (1607, 1620)] -> found match
APPENDED: (622, 635)

checking [(637, 642), (780, 785), (1341, 1346), (1944, 1949), (2044, 2049), (2158, 2163), (2594, 2599), (2643, 2648)] -> found match
APPENDED: (637, 642)

RESULT: [(1042, 1056), (895, 922), (966, 995), (692, 716), (667, 690), (667, 690), (667, 690), (479, 508), (1112, 1578), (1112, 1200), (275, 479), (450, 470), (500, 700), (0, 29), (820, 835), (622, 635), (637, 642)]
```